# Python Issue while login in to ajax website with a checkbox of terms and conditions

Tags: python, html, ajax, python-requests

I am getting this issue while loggin in to a ajax website, the issue is while login in it requires username, password and checkbox i agree with terms and conditions. I have tried login in with only username and password but it returns an error that you must agree with  terms and conditions Can any one help me with this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import csv
import urllib.request

URL = 'https://www.somesite.com/Login'
LOGIN_ROUTE = 'https://www.somesite.com/Login/Check'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.3'
HEADERS={'User-Agent':user_agent} 
s = requests.session()

csrf_token = s.get(LOGIN_ROUTE).cookies['__RequestVerificationToken']
print("\ncsrf_token " +csrf_token)

login_payload = {
        'Login.UserName': 'username',
        'Login.Password': 'password', 
        '__RequestVerificationToken': csrf_token
        }

login_req = s.post(LOGIN_ROUTE, headers=HEADERS, data=login_payload)

if login_req.status_code==200:
  print(str(login_req.status_code) + " login successful\n") #if successful, 200 will be returned
else:
  print(str(login_req.status_code) + " login unsuccessful")

cookies = login_req.cookies
soup = bs(login_req.text, 'html.parser')
print("Parse text begins here")
print(soup)
```

the returned page is :

```
<form 
    action="/Login/Login" 
    class="form-signin loginForm" 
    data-ajax="true" 
    data-ajax-begin="AjaxBegin()" 
    data-ajax-complete="AjaxComplete()" 
    data-ajax-method="POST" 
    data-ajax-success="Login(data)" 
    id="mainLoginForm" method="post" 
    role="form"
    >
    <input 
        name="__RequestVerificationToken" 
        type="hidden" 
        value="h3aO76bDCl0QOh7HOjH8XWKcyBPfbTR3E6KkF6jf3hL7gJPUbaLlP60gqrVYAxV6wHagvTQK_Azd1GWp50f08s59rnD87TIn2-zX55atrvY1"
        /> 
    <div class="col-sm-12 center_align_tablet">
        <input 
            autofocus="" 
            class="form-control" 
            data-val="true" 
            data-val-required="The Username field is required." 
            id="username" 
            name="Login.UserName" 
            placeholder="User Name" 
            required="" 
            style="" 
            type="text" 
            value=""
            />
        <span 
            class="field-validation-valid" 
            data-valmsg-for="Login.UserName" 
            data-valmsg-replace="true" 
            style="color:red"
            >
        </span>
        <input 
            class="form-control" 
            data-val="true" 
            data-val-required="The Password field is required." 
            id="loginPass" 
            name="Login.Password" 
            placeholder="Password" 
            required="" 
            style="margin-top:10px;" 
            type="password"
            />
        <span 
            class="field-validation-valid" 
            data-valmsg-for="Login.Password" 
            data-valmsg-replace="true" 
            style="color:red"
            >
        </span>
        <span id="LoginErrorMessage"></span>
        <p style="font-size:12px; margin-top:10px;"></p>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input class="agreeBox" type="checkbox" value=""/>
                    I Agree with the 
                    <a 
                        class="hyperlink" 
                        data-target="#terms_conditions_modal" 
                        data-toggle="modal" 
                        href="" 
                        id="termsPopUp"
                    >
                    Terms and Conditions
                    </a> 
                    of Acceptable Use
            </label>
            <div class="red" style="color:red;display:none">
                Please Agree With Terms &amp; Conditions
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-block login_btn_tablet" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </div>
</form> </div>
```

Comment: Your code cannot reproduce problem, because the true website is not shown.

Comment: Take a look at the request thats sent when you manually login (using chrome dev tools) and see if you can figure out the checkbox flag that's being added to the post request.

If that doesn't work, you can use selenium & chromedriver to login and send you the page info

Comment: If you provide actual URL then i can reproduce and solve problem for you, does not matter if the checkbox has id or name associated, it is however still possible to login successfully

Answer (score 0):

The returned page you've provided is suspicious, since the "agree checkbox" doesn't have any `name` or `id` attribute on it, so it seems that the checked value will not be passed to the backend even if it's flagged.

I would try to login on that website with the browser developer tools opened, under the network tab, and see which parameters are passed to the server when you login. Make sure you have "persist logs" checked.

If you don't find anything significant under the request's POST Parameters, i would give a look at the headers and cookies too.